# Hive query | use of group by in DML

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql, rdbms

I have created a Hive table as below:

```
create table db.tab_temp as select col1,col2,col3 from db.tab;
```

After this I ran the below query and got some rows.

```
select col1,col2,col3,count(*) from db.tab_temp group by col1,col2,col3 having count(*) >1;
```

Then I created another Hive table with same structure as below:

```
create table db.tab_temp1 as select col1,col2,col3 from db.tab group by col1,col2,col3;
```

Now for below query I am getting no rows.

```
select col1,col2,col3,count(*) from db.tab_temp1 group by col1,col2,col3 having count(*) >1;
```

Can anyone please explain the cause?

Comment: You mean initially you were getting the output for query but after you are not getting the output for same query please check your both queries are same even table name also "select col1,col2,col3,count() from db.tab_temp group by col1,col2,col3 having count() >1;"

Comment: @Strick
Yes for the first query I am getting output but for 2nd one not getting anything.
Only difference with both the tables is the way of creation. For 2nd table I have used group by.

Comment: @PawanKumar, May be the `having count(*)>1` condition is failing. Did you check the `count(*)` value? Can you post sample data so that we can replicate the issue and check further.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy, count(*) itself mentioned in select statement and I am getting it's value for 1st query.

Comment: @PawanKumar, are you checking `tab_temp` or `tab_temp1` in the last query? i believe it should be `tab_temp1` . Otherwise 2nd query and 4th query is exactly same

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy in 4th query I am fetching data from tab_temp1

Comment: Try your last query with `having count(*) >= 1`. You should get some data.